# ASP.NET MVC Data Annotation validate a group checkboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and working on the form validation. I am stuck with a group checkboxes validation. Basically, I am trying to make the user select at least one hobby in a group of checkboxes.

The model below. you can see that I tried to implement `AtLeastOneCheckedAttribute`, but couldn't get it to work properly.

```
public class EmployeeModel2
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please Provide First Name")]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "First Name Should be min 5 and max 20 length")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please Provide Last Name")]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "First Name Should be min 5 and max 20 length")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please Provide Eamil")]
    [RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", ErrorMessage = "Please Provide Valid Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please Provide Age")]
    [Range(25, 45, ErrorMessage = "Age Should be min 25 and max 45")]
    public int? Age { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Provide Gender")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Date of Birth")]
    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter ConfirmPassword")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Password not matching")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    
    public List<HobbyMV> Hobbies { get; set; }

    [AtLeastOneChecked(ErrorMessage = "Please select at least one checkbox")]
    public int[] selectedHobbies { get; set; }
}

// I tried this code, but it is not working properly
public class AtLeastOneCheckedAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var instance = value as IEnumerable<HobbyMV>;

        if (instance != null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The form in the view. The issue is that `selectedHobbies` group checkboxes keeps prompting "Please select at least one checkbox" even I selected a few checkboxes.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Validation2", "XForm", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new
{@class = "form"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", title = "Enter your first name" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", title = "Enter your last name" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LastName, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "form-control", title = "Enter your email address" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Age, new { @class = "form-control", title = "Enter your age" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Age, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>
 
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" >
        <label><b>Gender</b></label>
        <div> 
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, "Male") 
            <label>Male</label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Gender, "Female") 
            <label> Female </label>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Gender, "", new {@class = "text-danger"}) 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" >
        <label><b>Hobby</b></label><br/>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Hobbies)
        {
            <span style="padding:10px;">
                <label><input type="checkbox" value="@item.HobbyId" checked="@item.IsSelected" name="selectedHobbies" id="@item.HobbyId" /> @Html.Raw(@item.Description)</label>
            </span>
        }
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.selectedHobbies, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
    </div>

    <div class="form-group"> 
         <input type = "submit" value="Submit" class="btn-success" /> 
     </div>
}
```

If I selected some checkboxes for the hobby and click <kbd>Submit</kbd>, it did not pass the validation (screenshot below) and the message "Please select at least one checkbox" does not go away.

[image]

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your e-mail address validation regex is too strict, for example, it rejects Unicode e-mail addresses and IDN domain-names - as well as recently added TLDs (which are often longer than 6 chars...)

Comment: I am still learning.... would you mind provide me the regex that you would recommend for Email field?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use indexing to make list binding for the `Hobbies` to work correct:

```xml
<div class="form-group" >
    <label><b>Hobby</b></label><br/>   
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Hobbies.Count; i++)
    {
        <span style="padding:10px;">      
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(r => Model.Hobbies[i].IsSelected)
            @Html.Raw(@Model.Hobbies[i].Description)
            @Html.HiddenFor(h => @Model.Hobbies[i].HobbyId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(h => @Model.Hobbies[i].Description)
        </span>          
    }
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Hobbies, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Specify the `AttributeTargets.Property` for the custom attribute:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class AtLeastOneCheckedAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public AtLeastOneCheckedAttribute(string errorMessage) : base(errorMessage)
    {
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)    
    {
        // Check that list doesn't empty and at least one item is selected
        if (value is IEnumerable<HobbyMV> list && list.Any(h => h.IsSelected))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage); 
    }
}
```

And apply the `AtLeastOneChecked` attribute to the `Hobbies` list:

```cs
[AtLeastOneChecked("Please select at least one checkbox")]
public List<HobbyMV> Hobbies { get; set; }
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. Would you please explain the purpose there are two hidden fields that associate with each checkbox? How those hidden fields tied to the checkboxes? and the AttributeTargets.Property? Your solution works perferct, but I am new and just want to learn.

Comment: @Milacay: The `Html.HiddenFor`, for properties not used on the page, combining with indexing used to prepare the context, that will be send back to the `XForm` controller when sending the POST request. Therefore, in the `Validation2` action method all the `Hobbies` list will be received and you can analyze it content - enumerate list and check the `IsSelected` and use `HobbyId`, `Description` properties etc. But even more useful if `ModelState.IsValid` returns `false` we can render the same view again and pass the same data model to indicate errors.

Comment: `HiddenFor()` and `Hidden()` are using often to generate hidden input elements for the model properties to keep required data in context to help the default ASP.NET binding process to work properly. Try use right-click in a browser, then select `View Page Source` command to see/inspect what is generated when using `HiddenFor()` and `Hidden()` helpers. The [`AttributeTargets.Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attributetargets?view=net-8.0) specifies on which element is valid to apply this attribute. For example you can't apply it to the `class` etc.